# Referencing another collection may lead to huge queries

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections:

`Annotations`

```
{
  annotations: ["lion", "zebra", "cobra"],
  imagesId: 1234
}

{
  annotations: ["lion", "zebra", "cobra", "dog"],
  imagesId: 12345
}
```

`Images`

```
{_id:1234,
 name: "africa"
}
{_id:12345,
 name: "america"
}
```

I want to find all image names annotated with for example `zebra`.

This is my pseudo approach:

```
let annotations = Annotations.find({annotations: {'$in': 'zebra'}});  

getOnlyUniqueItems(annotations);  

Images.find({_id: {'$in': annotations}});
```

It will work, problem is when `annotations` contain for example 1M `ids`, then query itself will be more then 1MB of text, it will probably kill my database.

Question: what is the best approach to this problem?
Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we won't take in consideration that save `annotations` as a free text separated by `,` is a bad idea, and performance/response time are not issue for the specific use case you might give a try to [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html), something like:

```
Annotations.aggregate([
  { $match: { annotations: { '$in': 'zebra' } } },
  {
      $lookup:
         {
            from: "Images",
            localField: "imagesId",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "image"
        }
   }
]);
```

Comment: `annotations` is not a free text, it is a collection of {annotations, imagesid} objects.

Comment: Yeah, but `annotations` property inside `annotations` collection is a free text.

Comment: my mistake, it should be an array of strings: `annotations: ['zebra', 'lion', 'cobra']`

Comment: Does it change anything in your answer?

Comment: Not really, in anyway you have to use `$lookup`